# Loop through records in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql, loops

I have the following problem. I have two tables (created on another server from another developer):
BUSLines:
LineID int,
DepartureTime datetime,
...

BUSStops:
LineID int,
StopID int,
Hour int,
Minute int,
...

So, I need to get data in format:
LineID int,
StopID int,
StopDeparture datetime,
...

StopDeparture must be calculated for each StopID in a way that Hour and Minute is added to the previous StopDeparture for that line.

My idea was to select all the data in a temporary table and loop through the data to recalculate the departure times. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? If >= 2005, then a recursive CTE would be usefull without using a temp table & loop. Faster to boot. Sorry I don't have access to SQL Server to code one up. BTW, it would be nice to include create tables and some inserts with test data for the people writing answers.

Comment: How many stops per line on average?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the number of stops per line is not expected to be great you can use a triangular join for this.

```
WITH BUSLines(LineID, DepartureTime) AS
(
SELECT 1, CAST('1900-01-01T10:00:00' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
SELECT 2, CAST('1900-01-01T12:30:00' AS DATETIME) 
),
BUSStops(LineID,StopID,Hour,Minute) AS
(
SELECT 1,1,0,40 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,0,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,0,30 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,0,27 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3,1,15 
)
SELECT BL.LineID, 
       BS1.StopID, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE,SUM(BS2.Minute),DATEADD(HOUR,SUM(BS2.Hour),BL.DepartureTime))
FROM BUSLines BL
JOIN BUSStops BS1 ON BL.LineID = BS1.LineID
JOIN BUSStops BS2 ON BL.LineID = BS2.LineID AND BS2.StopID <= BS1.StopID
GROUP BY BL.LineID, BL.DepartureTime, BS1.StopID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursors for that. Here is quick example [example](http://www.jackdonnell.com/articles/SQL_CURSOR.htm). But be warned cursors are slow and I do not recommended them in many cases.